# QTimer format converting

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtimer

***I have this code:***

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
import sys


class Ui_Timer15(object):
    def setupUi(self, Timer):
        Timer.setObjectName("Timer")
        Timer.resize(321, 121)

        self.count = 5400
        self.start = False

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Timer)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 141, 31))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.start_action)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 301, 61))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("border : 3px solid black")
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 80, 141, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.pause_action)

        Timer.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Timer)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Timer)
        timer = QTimer(self.label)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        timer.start(1000)

    def showTime(self):

        # checking if flag is true
        if self.start:
            # incrementing the counter
            self.count -= 1
  
            # timer is completed
            if self.count == 0:
  
                # making flag false
                self.start = False
  
                # setting text to the label
                self.label.setText("Completed")
  
        if self.start:
            # getting text from count
            text = str(self.count)
  
            # showing text
            self.label.setText(text)

    def start_action(self):
        # making flag true
        self.start = True
  
        # count = 0
        if self.count == 0:
            self.start = False
    def pause_action(self):
  
        # making flag false
        self.start = False

    def retranslateUi(self, Timer):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Timer.setWindowTitle(_translate("Timer", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Timer", "Start"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Timer", "Pause"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Timer", "0"))
```

When I start the timer, i see:

[image: THIS]

***How I can convert this into hh:mm:ss ?***
I tried a lot of things but it doesn`t worked....

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Use QTime:

```
t = QTime(0, 0, 0).addSecs(self.count)
text = t.toString("hh:mm:ss")
self.label.setText(text)
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/5PSNWst

:(

Comment: `self.label.setText(text)` ...?

Comment: yes, i putted it

Comment: @eyllanesc QTime() returns an invalid time, and `addSecs()` doesn't change the QTime object but returns a new one. It should be `t = QTime(0, 0).addSecs(self.count)`.